# trying to specify MKMapView to within a frame but not working

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I'm trying the simplest thing but it's not working correctly. I have a MKMapView called mapView in a controller and in the viewDidLoad, I'm doing:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect myRect=CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f);
    self.mapView.frame = myRect;
}
```

but the MKMapView is still taking up the whole controller screen. What am I doing wrong?

thx

Comment: Are you using Interface Builder? and is the map being created in IB?

Comment: yes, just dragged a MapView into a Controller. Not sure if updating this way is possible

Comment: Do you have auto layout enabled?

Comment: Yes, autolayout is enabled

Answer (score 0):

If you have autolayout enabled, it will not pay attention to the frame. If you want to adjust the mapView size and/or position, I would turn off autolayout or add constraints in code.

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(10)-[mapView(100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"mapView" : self.mapView}]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(10)-[mapView(100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"mapView" : self.mapView}]];
```

Comment: hmm... I added a bracket at the end but was getting the following error when running `2013-12-02 16:10:44.966 ineedhelp[17712:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format: 
Unable to interpret '|' character, because the related view doesn't have a superview 
H:|-(10)-[mapView(100)] ` I literally just dropped this onto a UIViewController; do I need to put this within a container or something? thx

Comment: Check your view hierarchy in Storyboard, mapView the only view? Does it not have a superview? Usually when you drag a view controller into storyboard it contains a view object

Comment: I think you raised a correct issue, somehow the view was gone and the MapView was like the top level view. Def a mistake on my end. I tried your constrains and the width and height worked but the offsets didn't (I needed to add a bracket at end). hmm... let me play with this a bit

Comment: Is there really not a way to do this  by just adjusting frame?

Comment: @timpone AutoLayout will override any value you set on the frame. If you initialize the mapView in code rather then adding it in IB, adjusting the frame should work.